# Limit number of concurrent user logins in Windows Server 2008 Active Directory

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, login, user-management

Is there the possibility to limit Active Directory users' max concurrent login sessions?

I've read many articles and discussions about the solution, but none of them seem to be working.

Many had suggested UserLogin script that doesn't work in Windows Server 2008. Some other suggested CConnect that is not good enough. It's also very complicated. Some others have introduced UserLock that should be paid for.

It's wondering that Windows Server 2003 DOES have the feature (wile as a third-party), but Windows Server 2008 doesn't have!

One of the articles I've read: http://www.edugeek.net/forums/windows-server-2008-r2/61216-multiple-logins.html

Comment: I don't think that Microsoft really see this as a problem that needs solving - lets face it, outside of education and other specialist situations what's the business case for enabling this? As someone who works in education, however, I do have the need and to be honest we just trialed userlock (mentioned in the edugeek thread I believe), discovered it works really well, placed an order and then got on with our day... Not the answer you were looking for, I appreciate, but the best I have. You can stop multiple logins with scripting of course, for free, but that just causes more problems...

Answer (score 3):

There is no built-in functionality in any version of Windows Server to do what you're asking for. You're going to have to write something yourself or procure third-party software.

The only thing even remotely close built-in would be to limit the computers the account can log in to (through ADUC for instance).  In essence, if you took the time to limit an account to a single workstation, then it almost gives you the functionality.  But it's a PITA to administer and is more of a workaround to the request.